# Sales tax calculation algorithm

Tags: calculation, sales-tax

I need to code a tax calculation algorithm for a project.

**What is the correct algorithm for calculating sales taxes on an sales receipt?**

Given a sales receipt with 3 items (A,B,C) and a 4 taxes (W,X,Y,Z)
Is this correct?

```
Round(AW + AX + AY + AZ)
+
Round(BW + BX + BY + BZ)
+
Round(CW + CX + CY + CZ)
```

or

```
Round(AW + BW + CW)
+
Round(AX + BX + CX)
+
Round(AY + BY + CY)
+
Round(AZ + BZ + CZ)
```

or

```
Round(AW + AX + AY + AZ + BW + BX + BY + BZ + CW + CX + CY + CZ)
```

or something else?

I've tried many algorithms and keep running into penny rounding issues when comparing to the TaxJar API calculation results.

I **assume** that each tax (State, County, City, Special) has to be applied to each line item (or possible each item if the qty > 1), then summed and rounded on a per tax basis.

Is there a definitive resource for this algorithm I can use? or a online calculator that breaks down the calculations so I can compare it with my code?

Finally, what type of rounding should be used and when should it be applied?

Comment: Every state has different taxable and untaxable items. Rounding binary numbers often produces different results from rounding decimal numbers, nut that's va programming issue, not a finance issue. _Technically_ your question is offtopic here, since it's about business finance and software development rather than personal finance, but it's an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that each tax (State, County, City, Special) has to be
> applied to each line item (or possible each item if the qty > 1), then
> summed and rounded on a per tax basis.

I am not a sales tax expert but I do know that in the states where I have lived your assumption is not true.

You would calculate the total of all the items that are taxable by jurisdiction W and then multiply the total by W's rate to get the tax going to W. In my experience the resulting tax is always rounded up to the next penny if it isn't exact to the penny. In most languages this would be a ceiling function.

For example if the total for jurisdiction W is $3.00 and the rate is 5% the tax is 15 cents. If the total was $3.01 the tax would be 16 cents.

The tax would then be calculated the same way for X, Y and Z. Each of these calculations would be shown on the receipt. It is possible that some items wouldn't be taxable by all jurisdictions, so you probably can't combine the rates and do a single multiplication and rounding, unless the taxing authorities allow it.

Comment: Often there is a tax lookup table provided, rather than simply a tax rate. And weird things can happen. A common lunch I buy nearby ends up being $11.99 including tax. There is no way to arrange a base price so the total is $12.00 - the next possible price with tax is $12.01.